# Css для хлебных крошек :last-child:after

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтобы в последнем элементе в хлебных крошках не было сепаратора.
Не пойму почему не работает.
Пример:

```css
.breadcrumbs li a:after{display:inline-block;padding-left:5px;content:'»';}
.breadcrumbs li a:last-child:after {content: none;}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
     <ul>
 <li><a href=" ">Главная</a></li>
 <li><a href=" ">Категория</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lysywyhx/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lysywyhx/1/

Comment: Как правило последний элемент хлебных крошек неактивен, там нет ссылок

Answer (score 5, accepted):

:last-child не туда добавили: надо к `li`.

```css
.breadcrumbs li a:after {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  content: '»';
}

.breadcrumbs li:last-child a:after {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href=" ">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href=" ">Категория</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: чуток опередил меня с ответом ....

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.breadcrumbs li+li:before{
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left:5px;
  content:'»';
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href=" ">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href=" ">Категория</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Обидно что нет ответа с селектором `:not()` - [подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```css
/* Все span кроме :last-child имеют ::after */
.crumb > span:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '>';
  display: inline;
  color: red;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="crumb">
  <span>soRU</span>
  <span>questions</span>
  <span>css для хлебных крошек last-childafter</span>
</div>
```